# how to keep goods'info in invoice form?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use three tables to save invoices:

1. Invoice
2. InvoiceDetail
3. TempInvoiceDetail

when user add goods i add goods in TempInvoiceDetail.

then user select all goods and click on "Save Invoice".

i add one row in Invoice then move all row from TempInvoiceDetail to InvoiceDetail
,then Delete TempInvoiceDetail.

i save userid
is it true?
do u have any idea?

Comment: I don't know if it is true - if this is what happens in your application, I guess it is true. Do you mean to ask if this is a good design?

Comment: @Oded , she means 'good' as 'Commodity'. as she is my compatriot I know what she means.

Comment: my freind said to me better way is save goods'info into session Instead of TempInvoiceDetail

Comment: @Shaahin - I have no problem with using `goods` & `commodity`. It's the use of `true`. She is asking if what she describes is in fact what is happening. I assume she means to as if the design she describes is a good/valid one.

Comment: @Oded ,  She wants to ask this : User selects goods , count of goods , unit of goods after then user want to save items and seeing his invoice is it better to keep selected data in Temp table or session ?

Answer (score 1):

The design you have is fine as it is.

No need to change the temporary invoicing to sessions, though a better design might be to have a `status` field on the `Invoice` table to say if this is a temporary or final invoice.

Comment: One could instead have the concept of a 'provisional invoice' stored within the invoice tables proper - and saving an invoice marks the invoice as 'live' and presumably sets the invoice number.

Comment: @Oded , Why temp table is better than keeping object in session ? or another way serializing object ?

Comment: @shaahin - If you have a web farm, you will not be able to share information that is in the process memory.

Comment: do u think session is faster than tempTable?

Comment: @Niloofar  - It probably is faster, but there are other considerations.

Comment: Would you please describe about considerations ? or giving link for more information ?

Comment: @shaahin - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354360/storing-user-variables-in-database-vs-session-in-asp-net